# Get keys in chunks from AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

We have a huge number of keys in a bucket, `B`, in S3, and we need to download them from s3 using `boto` and then iterate over all of them in python. The only way we've found so far of getting the keys is by calling `list()`, which tries to download all the keys from `B` at once, i.e.:

```
bucket = boto.connect_s3().get_bucket(`B`)
keys = bucket.list()
```

This always hangs for us, presumably due to the huge number of keys. It works fine if we get the keys for a different bucket with a smaller number of total keys, or if a prefix is used. We would like to avoid using a prefix for bucket `B` for project-specific reasons. Is there any way to get all the keys from `B`, but in chunks?

Comment: Considering http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.list as reference, boto's call list() also provides pagination feature. Only thing is that you will have to iterate it and store key list in some other list.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `Bucket` object itself as a generator, like this:

```
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket('foo')
for key in bucket:
    <do stuff with key>
```

When used in this manner, the `Bucket` object will do the pagination of results for you in the background and only grab a page of keys at a time.